# jspdf is generating a corrupted pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, zip, jspdf, jszip

https://jsfiddle.net/yt92n1pt/49/

The pdf generated in the above fiddle is corrupted according to Acrobat reader, but renders fine in Google Chrome. Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

Edit: The question was originally asking why the contents of a zipped pdf were different when compared to the original pdf. But that's not the case.

[image: Original PDF]
[image: Zipped PDF]

```
window.create_zip = function() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  addHtml(document.getElementById('tables').outerHTML, pdf).then(function(){
    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.file("notok.pdf", pdf.output());
    zip.generateAsync({
      type: "blob"
    })
      .then(function(content) {
      saveAs(content, "example.zip");
    });
  });
}

window.create_pdf = function() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  addHtml(document.getElementById('tables').outerHTML, pdf).then(function(){
    pdf.save('ok.pdf');
  });
}


function addHtml(html, doc) {
  var canvas = doc.canvas;
  canvas.pdf = doc;

  html = html.replace(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi, '');

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('style','position:fixed;left:15px; top:15px; display: none');
  div.setAttribute('id', 'hidden_div_123');
  document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

  return html2canvas(div.firstChild, {canvas : canvas, onclone: _onclone}).then(function(canvas) {
    if (div) {
      div.parentElement.removeChild(div);
    }
  });

  function _onclone(clone) {
    $(clone.getElementById('hidden_div_123')).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is a funny thing...I have Acrobat Reader DC installed, when I open both filed with Adobe Reader, the program complaint that both files have corrupted data...but if I open the files and if I choose to open the files with google chrome, they both display correctly!

Comment: You are right, I just tested on Windows with Acrobat Reader and both are corrupted. On Google Chrome both are ok. What's weird for me is that I checked both files using a text viewer and found many differences. Anyway, I know now that there is a problem with jsPDF and no problem with jszip. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help @Edhowler

Comment: neither Adobe Reader nor Chrome is a PDF validator, they ignore certain errors but different ones due to implementation details.

Comment: You can replace the spaces with `&nbsp;` https://jsfiddle.net/8mu4hbhe/2/

Comment: @GramThanos, thank you, it worked! Do you mind answering the question so I can mark as solved?

Comment: @Edhowler I wasn't sure if it was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe PDF seems to crash on the spaces between words.
One solution that may work on your case it to replace the spaces with `&nbsp;`.

In order to make it a little dynamic, we need to replace the spaces in any child that don't have any other child (that has only text inside).

```
// Replace spaces with non-breaking space (nbsp)
var tags = div.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
    if (tags[i].children.length == 0 && tags[i].innerHTML.length > 0) {
        tags[i].innerHTML = tags[i].innerHTML.replace(/ /gm, '&nbsp;');
    }
}
```

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/8mu4hbhe/2/